# Return all positions of strings that contain a given substring

Tags: r, string

I have a set of string like this

> ```
> [[1]]
>
> [1] "The quick brown fox jumped over the sleeping lazy dog"
>
> [2] "The fox quickly turned around"
>
> [3] "The sun rises every day"
>
> [4] "Be quick on your feet"
> ```

I want to return a vector with positions of all the string that contain a substring "quick"

The result should be

> ```
> pos
>
> [1]    1    4
> ```

I have tried

```
pmatch("quick", x, nomatch = NA_integer_, duplicates.ok = TRUE)
```

but that returns an NA value.

Comment: `grep("\\bquick\\b", txt)`

Comment: It looks like your character vector is in a list. Try `pmatch("quick", x[[1]], ...)`, and if you don't want to match "quickly" use the word boundaries as user20650 suggests.

Comment: @user20650, that worked with a minor change, thank you. As Gregor mentioned, I am using a list, and hence this worked. 
`pos <- grep(key_word, txt[[1]])`